jqassistant-npm-plugin scan throws InvalidFormatException for org.jqassistant.plugin.npm.impl.scanner.Package$Person
When running scan of package.json I get the following exception:
Cannot scan item /Projects/jqassistant-npm-project-scan/package.json
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot coerce empty String ("") to org.jqassistant.plugin.npm.impl.scanner.Package$Person value (but could if coercion was enabled using CoercionConfig)
at [Source: (FileInputStream); line: 21, column: 13] (through reference chain: org.jqassistant.plugin.npm.impl.scanner.Package["author"])
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException.from(InvalidFormatException.java:67)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadCoercion(DeserializationContext.java:1817)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._checkCoercionFail(StdDeserializer.java:1662)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromEmptyString(StdDeserializer.java:325)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromString(StdDeserializer.java:270)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1504)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:197)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4825)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3809)
at org.jqassistant.plugin.npm.impl.scanner.PackageJsonScannerPlugin.scan(PackageJsonScannerPlugin.java:44)
at org.jqassistant.plugin.npm.impl.scanner.PackageJsonScannerPlugin.scan(PackageJsonScannerPlugin.java:27)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:125)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:89)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:64)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.common.impl.scanner.FileScannerPlugin.scan(FileScannerPlugin.java:35)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.plugin.common.impl.scanner.FileScannerPlugin.scan(FileScannerPlugin.java:21)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:125)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:85)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.core.scanner.impl.ScannerImpl.scan(ScannerImpl.java:64)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:103)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.lambda$scanFiles$4(ScanTask.java:93)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.scanFiles(ScanTask.java:83)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.lambda$run$0(ScanTask.java:61)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresentOrElse(Optional.java:201)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.lambda$run$2(ScanTask.java:60)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.AbstractStoreTask.withStore(AbstractStoreTask.java:52)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.task.ScanTask.run(ScanTask.java:51)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.Main.executeTask(Main.java:311)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.Main.executeTasks(Main.java:270)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.Main.interpretCommandLine(Main.java:209)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:89)
at com.buschmais.jqassistant.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:70)

This looks like a bug in the scanner implementation, can you create an issue for it?
